# Salesforce Formula Field always equals null in Apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, force.com

I have a formula field "Asset MRR" defined for the Asset object.
The value of this field is defined to always equal 100:
[image]

But when I try to access "Asset MRR" field in Apex, `asset.Asset_MRR__c` equals `null` for some reason:

```
static testMethod void assetTriggerTest2() {
        Account account = new Account(Name='SFDC Account');
        insert account;

        Asset asset = new Asset(Name='asset name', AccountId = account.Id);
        insert asset;

        // System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: 100
        System.assertEquals(asset.Asset_MRR__c, 100); 
    }
```

While in Salesforce interface the value of `asset.Asset_MRR__c` is 100, like it's supposed to be:
[image]

**Why does `asset.Asset_MRR__c` equal `null` in Apex? Why isn't it 100?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-query for the record and include the field.

Asset asset = [Select ID, Name, Asset_MMR__c from Asset where id =: asset.id limit 1][0];

System.assertEquals(asset.Asset_MRR__c, 100);